# what is the sql system variable for timeout for cross server calls?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timeout

I had a similar problem to the issue below and I think I found a solution but I just need to know the sql system variable for what the connection timeout is I tried @@LOCK_TIMEOUT but that only works if you set the time out. However, shouldn't there be a default time out for when the sql server connection just times out or a variable that stores this information just in case the dba increased or decreased the timeout of the connection and not just the session. Because if the time out is not set on the session level and it is set on the server level than @@LOCK_TIMEOUT is still -1.

Similar issue:
[Handling Timeouts inside stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563501/handling-timeouts-inside-stored-procedures/3563523)
What I was planning on doing is the following:

@start = SYSDATETIME()
exec stored_proc  cross server call to sp 
@end = SYSDATETIME()
IF @end-@start = @LOCK_TIMEOUT1 (@Lock_timeout1 would be the time out for the sp being called from this SP)
BEGIN
Raiserror('Timeout occurred for sp in cross server call', 16, 1)
END

Comment: Why is this tagged `oracle`?

Comment: sorry about that I was multitasking.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it this is what I have so far:

```
SET @TimeoutCheck =(SELECT CONVERT(INT,VALUE) FROM crossserver.sys.configurations WHERE      configuration_id=1520)
SET @start=GETDATE()

Exec crossserver.processthissp @ProcessID

IF @@error<>0 
BEGIN 
    Raiserror('Error in crossserver.processthissp', 16,1)
    Return 
END 
SET @end=GETDATE()
SELECT @TimeoutCheck/60,DATEDIFF(mi, @start, @end)

IF DATEDIFF(mi, @start, @end) > @TimeoutCheck/60 
BEGIN
    RaisError('Job failed due to cross server timeout.',16,1)
    Return -1
END
```