# How to handle TimeOut inside Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure in which the classic TRY/CATCH error handling does not seem to apply due to a connection time-out.

Environment: MSSQL 2012, PHP 5.4, Win 2008 Server

The stored procedure invokes a new connection to a **remote linked server** and tries to pass the query along. The timeout happens during the connection process (see the code block below) not the query itself. This timeout generates an exception error to ADODB layer which makes the application layer (PHP) script fail. Any idea how to CATCH such timeout ?

Code block:

```
SET @sql0 = 'SELECT @flag = 1 FROM ' + @server_name + '.[Database].[dbo].[sysobjects] 
AS sysobjcts WHERE [sysobjcts].[name] =''remote_table'' '

execute sp_executesql @sql0, N'@flag INT OUTPUT', @flag = @flag OUTPUT

   -- if table exist
   IF @flag = 1 BEGIN
    ...
```

The above is my simple way to check if the required table exist on the remote server before I try to query it (point of failure). I need to solve it on my end not on the remote linked server.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3563522/65775

Comment: @Keith - thanks, I saw that and the attached link post as well, that is not what my case.

Comment: ...more I read and think about this, I do not believe there is anything on the database level which could handle it. Since I am using ADODB the solution will have to be transferred to the application layer. Please prove me wrong.

Comment: True. Are all of your linked server queries taking time? If so there is a networking\configuration issue that needs to be diagnosed and fixed.